# Usage of Stack Exchange API (v2.2)

Tags: discussion, api, legal

I was planning to use the API to search for relevant answers to certain questions and then display the output, in Actions on Google. Would doing that violate the policy of fair use or something? (Actions on Google would be a part of the Google Assistant)

Would I need to give a link to the webpage of the answer from which the text has been extracted and shown there?

And is it needed to officially mail and ask for permission from SO?

Comment: Most of that is in the legal spk [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) and [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)  and from that *In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content outside of the Network or Services, with the exception of content entirely created by You, You agree that You will follow the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license as follows:* and then there are 5 bullets to be aware of.

Comment: @rene I am afraid that I am not able to understand you completely. Could you please put it in a more simple way? What does "outside of the Network or Services," mean. And I read the "Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license" from https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/in/ and it says that I need to give proper attribution. Would that be required in every answer or would it be enough to just add it in the description of my Action on Google

Comment: I'm not an lawyer. For what you describe to use the API for is I think what covers *outside of the Network or Services*. And proper attribution means: You will ensure that: any such Internet use of Subscriber Content includes a hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site on the Network; any such use of Subscriber Content visually display or otherwise clearly indicate the author names for every question and answer so used; any such Internet use of Subscriber Content Hyperlink each author name directly back to his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network

Comment: So just a single blurb of text in your description is also required but not enough but again: I don't work for SE, I didn't write the ToS, I'm not a lawyer, I know nothing ...

Comment: @rene Could you suggest me, from where would I be able to get the exact answer? Do I need to mail SE? The thing is that there is a limited word limit in the output of the Actions on Google that I am talking about. So I might anyway have to shorten the answer and then give a link back to the website for the full description or something like that. Adding the name with each answer, is needed you mean to say? Thank you so much for taking the time out and helping me

Comment: Well, you're at the right place. But it might take some time before an SE employee who has the authority to answer this will chime in. Give it 6 to 8 days. In the mean time you might want to add to your question how you interpret the Terms of Service, maybe combined with what is answered in other or similar cases [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/legal).

Comment: Exact answer can be found at http://stackexchange.com/legal

Comment: Note that DuckDuckGo already has a form of 'instant answers' on their search engine which references answers from some SE sites. Example search: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=if+__name__+%3D%3D+%22__main__%22%3A&t=hz&atb=v68-6&ia=qa